# Can an element in a Noetherian ring have arbitrarily long factorizations?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Suppose $R$ is a Noetherian ring.  Is it possible that an element $r\in R$ have arbitrarily long factorizations? That is, for all $n>0$, is there a factorization $r=a_{1n}a_{2n}\cdots a_{nn}$ such that each $a_{in}$ is a non-unit? If this is not possible, what about the weaker hypothesis of ascending chain condition on principal ideals? It is evident that this cannot happen in a UFD.

Comment: Reposted [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1407411/can-an-element-in-a-noetherian-domain-have-arbitrarily-long-factorizations) under the assumption that $R$ is an integral domain.

Answer (score 6):

You can even have arbitrarily long factorizations with a *finite* ring.

Take the field of two elements $F$, form $R=F\times F$, and let $e=(1,0)$. Then $e$ is not a unit and $e=e^n$ for any positive integer.

Of course, if you want to rule out idempotents like this you can by looking at domains and local rings. <s>As other posters have explained,</s> your luck will definitely better with Noetherian domains.

Addendum: there was a comment and a solution that I was referring to that no longer appear here. The solution for domains was moved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1407437/29335).

Comment: I could duplicate information that appears in better-asked questions elsewhere, but that would not be a good use of time, especially considering that is not the main question here. I've provided a link, though, to fill the reference you broke when moving your solution. Regards.